# how do you attach a document from googleappengine in sendgrid?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, sendgrid

how do you attach a document from googleappengine in sendgrid?
I have tried the direct url : it doesnt work setAttachment('http...');
gt contents like: ->simple_get($_SESSION['document'][0]) but l cant recreate a file in the base directory so it becomes useless,

May l please be assisted in solving it

Answer (score 1):

If you are using (can use) the latest SendGrid v3 API along with the SendGrid Client Library, you can use this example: https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php/blob/master/examples/helpers/mail/example.php#L82

Note that the attachment must be [base64 encoded](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php).

Otherwise, you can find documentation for the v3 /mail/send endpoint here for direct access: 
https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Send/v3_Mail_Send/index.html
https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Mail/index.html

Comment: Thank you Elmer, l will give it a shot